# Sample calculation from a big population

Tags: sample-size

I would like to calculate my sample from a working population of 583 890. The population mean and standard deviation is unknown.
The confidence interval has been selected as 95%.
Kindly help

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

No expert by any means, but I'll attempt an answer.
The general rule of thumb would be 10% of the estimated population, unless it is very large, as is your case.
You could potentially get away with 1% in your case, i.e. 5,000 or so, or even less, unless you are planning to dividing up that data into subgroups, etc.

It really depends on the cost and time of the sampling... if you already have the data, and there is no expensive cost to use more data, a higher percentage could certainly be used, but may not make a great difference in the results.